# Melhor método para localizar valores em um DataTable

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

Em uma tela de cadastro de unidade de medida, tenho que verificar se a unidade que o usuario esta querendo cadastrar, se ja existe, entao como tenho um `DataGrid` populado por um `DataTable`, pensei em percorrer o `DataTable` e verificar se esse ja existe.

Então fiz o codigo assim:

```
 //botão salvar
 private void simpleButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        //Verifico se os dois textbox estao preenchidos
        if (textBox1.Text != string.Empty && textBox2.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            // defino minha string de filtro
            string exp = "SIGLA = " + "'" + textBox2.Text + "'";
            // Executo a busca com base no meu filtro
            DataRow[] find_sigla = dat.Select(exp);

            // se o retorno da busca for 0 faz a ação
            if (find_sigla.Count() == 0)
            {
                //Insiro o valor no banco
                Classes.Cadastro.Cadastro_estqUn cad_estqun = new Classes.Cadastro.Cadastro_estqUn();
                if (cad_estqun.cadastro_unidade(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text) > 0)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = "";
                    textBox2.Text = "";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unidade de medida já cadastrada.", "Salvar", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
        }
    }
```

Então ouvi dizer, que esse método tenho perca de performance, procede? alguém tem alguma solução melhor?

Obrigado.

Comment: Seu dat está sendo carregador como?  E qual sua intenção!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu não confiaria no que está na DataGrid, mas sim no que está no banco de dados.

Um exemplo hipotético mas se aplica a outras situações reais:

"Seu sistema tem um servidor de banco de dados e 3 estações de trabalho. Seu usuário abriu essa tela e tinha 5 unidades de medidas, mas foi almoçar. Enquanto ele almoçava alguém cadastrou a unidade de medida que ele ia cadastrar. Vai duplicar no banco de dados se ele cadastrar depois do almoço, pois a DataGrid está desatualizada."

Nessa sua classe `Cadastro_estqUn` faça uma implementação que verifique no banco de dados se já existe o registro com a descrição. Seria algo assim:

```
public bool UnidadeMedidaUnica(string nome) 
{
  string sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbUnidadeMedida WHERE unidade_nome = @nome";
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlComman(sql, connectionString);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", nome);
  SqlDataReader mySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  int qtde = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
  return qtde == 0;
```

}

Para melhorar ainda pode adicionar um "unique index", que vai garantir que até instruções SQL disparadas diretamente no banco de dados dupliquem registros.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_unidade_nome ON tbUnidadesMedida(unidade_nome)
```

Comment: Realmente Murilo, essa situação pode acontecer, e com certeza e frequente. Fiz a implantação realizando um `COUNT` na tabela de unidade de medida em questão.